# Why is a laravel sanctum protected route returning 401 error code with a react spa both on localhost?

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

I have read several other post here on stack overflow and I could not find the answer to my question.

Since the user is logged in, the `/files` route should return a http 200.

I have a laravel APi with url `https://localhost:8090` and a react frontend with url `https://localhost:3000`.

Sanctum requires the api and the front-end to be on the same top-level domain, which they are (localhost).

I can successfully make a request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` and then `/login` which both returns a 204 code, and properly sets the cookies.

[image: Cookies view from dev console]
[image: network tab]
[image: Response headers]
[image: Request headers]

Below is my js code:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
 
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://localhost:8090',
    withCredentials: true,
});

export const login = (email, password) => {
    apiClient.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(() => {
        apiClient.post('/login', {
            email,
            password
        }).then(response => {
            apiClient.get('api/files').then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
        })
    });
};
```

I have tried many different combination of env settings, here is how it is right now:

```
APP_URL=https://localhost:8090
SESSION_DRIVER=file # Tried cookie also
CLIENT_ORIGIN=https://localhost:3000
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true # Tried false also
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000 # Tried a lot of combination here
```

My `cors.php` file is like this:

```php
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => [env('CLIENT_ORIGIN')],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => ['Content-Disposition'],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

My login route: (in web.php)

```php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'web',
], function () {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthenticationController::class, 'login']);
});
```

The route I am trying to access after logging in: (in api.php)

```php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:sanctum',
], function () {
    Route::get('/files', 'FileController@all');
});
```

My `Kernel.php` file:

```php
 protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \Mz\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        ],
        'web' => [
            \Mz\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \Mz\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: You have not explained in the question what your problem is. If it's in those images, do not assume that all users can see them.

Comment: The problem is the 401 error response while it should return success code 200 because the user is authentified and logged in.